# Java Stream only copies first line when input is pasted

Tags: java, java-stream

With the following code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(s.hasNext())
            result.add(s.next());
        s.close();
        return result;
```

If my input is entered manually on the terminal like this:

```
123
456
789
```

Everything is ok.

But if I copy and paste the input into the terminnal, the output is:

```
789
```

Only the last line of the input.

Using: CMD, JDK 14, Windows 10

Full code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
    private static ArrayList<String> readLines() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(s.hasNext())
            result.add(s.next());
        s.close();
        return result;
    }

    private static int[] convertLine(String line) {
        char[] digits = line.toCharArray();
        int[] result = new int[digits.length];
        int n = 0;
        for (char a : digits)
            result[n++] += a-48;
        return result;
    }

    private static int[][] convertLines(ArrayList<String> a) {
        int[][] result = new int[a.size()][];
        int n = 0;
        for (String line : a)
            result[n++] = convertLine(line);
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"resource"})
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] cells = convertLines(readLines());
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(cells[i][j]);
        System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: You need to call `nextLine()` at some point to get over the line terminators.

Comment: @user207421 No you don't. The tokens returned `next()` are whitespace-separated, which includes line terminators.

Comment: Don’t call `close()` on a `Scanner` wrapping `System.in`. You should never close the standard input.

Comment: @Holger This was the answer! I implemented it with another method and now that I look back, the difference is exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Holger's comment ended up being the solution.

By closing System.in, subsequent method executions can't reuse System.in. So when all text is posted into System.in one at a time, no problems occur, but when text is posted all at once, that's when problems arise. That's because closing System.in is undefined behavior, hence why it might or might not occur in different situations.

To keep the code split into individual methods, the Scanner should be opened in the main function and passed as an argument to the methods that need it.